# How to expand atan2 to plus/minus 3pi

Tags: matlab, difference, distortion, phase, atan2

I want to estimate the phase of harmonic distorted tones when having input tones with random initial phase within [-pi;pi]. I used atan2, build-in function of Matlab, however the phase jump at -pi or pi makes my calculation of phase difference having trouble.

The problem is as follow: there is a nonlinear system, and I want to estimate system's response (amplitude and phase responses). I insert many tones as x[n] = Acos(2*pi*fn*t+b), where fn is frequency, b is the initial random phase within [-pi;pi], and it changes with various tones. If a tone has initial phase b, then 2nd order harmonic distortion (HD) has phase of c=2b, and 3rd HD has phase of d=3b. The phase differences of the HD2 and HD3 could be c/2-b and d/3-b, respectively. Because of the memory effect of the system, the phase differences are no longer zero.

Issues: if the phase of input signal is large, e.g., 70 degree, then HD3 phase is 210 degree, when the phase angle >180, atan2 operation makes a jump to -180 and the HD3 phase become -150 degree instead of 210. Theoretically, cosd(210) = cosd(-150). However, what I want to find is the phase difference. That why, (-150/3-70) leads to a wrong results (it should be 0 if there is no memory effect). Similar situation for the case if input signal has large negative phase and for both HD2 and HD3. The major cause is antan2 limitation of [-pi;pi], and I want to expand to [-3pi;3pi].

Please help.

Thank you very much.
Regards

Comment: “Expand atan2” makes no sense, it is an operation that works on individual pairs, and would not be able to guess when to add or subtract 2pi. You’ll have to explain when phase unwrapping as demonstrated  below doesn’t work, so that me might understand your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It would not be able to guess when to add or subtract 2pi. I think some tricks to remove those jumps after getting phase response may help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is `unwrap`, e.g.,

```matlab
>>> angles=[-0.7*pi -0.9*pi 0.9*pi 0.7*pi]
angles =
  -2.1991e+00  -2.8274e+00   2.8274e+00   2.1991e+00
>>> unwrap(angles)/pi
ans =
  -7.0000e-01  -9.0000e-01  -1.1000e+00  -1.3000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work in my case. Unwrap can retrieve a jump of a consecutive phase variation. In my case, abrupted changes in phase happen at various iterations (sweeping tones). And thus, expanding atan2 up to -/+ 3pi is the best solution to estimate the phase at each iteration. I don't want a jump since I need those phase for further subtraction.

Comment: Then there has to be some extra info that’ll tell you when those abrupt changes happen to let you distinguish between a big jump from 0.9pi to -0.9pi vs a small jump from 0.9pi to 1.1pi. You need to add more details to the question saying what that info is.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my question and hope this help.